# Mongoengine unique_with

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with MongoDB. I have to make a Document in which the tuple (merchant_id, order_id, event_type) has to be a unique key.

Till now, I have always dealt with uniqueness being limited to two fields. So the following works-

```
merchant_id = StringField(required = True)
order_id = StringField(required = True, unique_with = 'merchant_id')
```

Now, I'm trying to do this for three fields -

```
merchant_id = StringField(required = True)
order_id =  StringField(required = True)
event_type = StringField(
    required = True,
    unique_with = ['merchant_id', 'order_id'])
```

But this doesn't work. I'm not getting an error in the module. But if I enter data as -

```
merchant_id = 'Merchant1'
order_id = 'Order1'
event_type = 'Event1'
```

and then try to add another data with the same `merchant_id` and `order_id` but a different `event_id`, then it gives an error about being a duplicate key.

I have also tried:

```
merchant_id = StringField(required = True)
order_id =  StringField(required = True)
event_type = StringField(
    required = True,
    unique_with = ('merchant_id', 'order_id'))
```

Comment: I got what the problem was.

It seems that once your collection has been made, you cannot change the unique key. So previously the uniqueness was on two fields and then later I changed it to three fields. So it was taking the first key defined.

For the latest key defined to take effect, one has to drop the collection altogether by using drop_collection().

Then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify an existing index's parameters, you have to drop the index first and then recreate it. Of course you cannot create a unique index on collections that contain duplicates. Either you must remove the duplicates first, or use the 'dropDups' index creation option.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify [indexes](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html#indexes) in the meta dict of the class

```
meta = {
    'indexes': [
        {'fields': ('merchant_id', 'order_id'), 'unique': True}
    ]
}
```